# Software to easily lay a song over a slideshow of images

Tags: software-recommendation, images, video

**Before you read this, I know that there are LOADS of programs that can easily do what I'm after; I'm cut short for time and I just don't have the hours to try out a numerous software to find out that something may not work or suite my need.**

I want to put together a slideshow for my friends wedding (this Saturday!) that includes images of him and his fiance with a 4 minute song playing over the top of it, so it should be a VERY simple task.

I want the images to last about 4-5 seconds each with a basic fade transition.

What would be the simplest program for this task?

Bear in mind I need this exported as a video but I don't know what software the laptop at the wedding reception will have so I will want to export a few file types (.mp4 .wmv .avi).

Any help greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Do you have After Effects? You could also do this in Photoshop, then mux music in. Those hit close home so your not so  unacustomed to the tools.

Comment: @joojaa I don't have After Effects but I do have Photoshop CS5, How would I do this in Photoshop? is there a quick process to apply a basic timed fade transition between images and just put music over the top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Picasa. It was perfect for loading a folder of images, choosing timed transition and then adding a sound track.